# Is my employer withholding too much?

Tags: united-states, withholding

I'm confused with the tax withholding on Federal Insurance Contributions Act (FICA) Medicare Hospital Insurance. It is supposed to be calculated as a fixed percentage (1.45%) of my gross income, with no income cap. While this should be simple to calculate, I can't get the numbers to match. I changed everything by a factor, but the proportions should be the same. I match the first paychecks by 1.45% multiple, but my employer seems to be taking more out than that. Any idea what is going on?

| PayDate | Income | FedFICAMedHospitalIns_EE | FedFICAMedHospitalIns_EE_calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/14/2021 | $2,087.55 | $30.27 | $30.27 |
| 5/21/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.25 | $28.21 |
| 5/28/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.46 | $27.02 |
| 6/4/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.28 | $27.02 |
| 6/11/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.27 | $27.02 |
| 6/18/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.29 | $28.03 |
| 6/25/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.28 | $28.03 |
| 7/2/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.28 | $28.03 |
| 7/9/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.29 | $28.03 |
| 7/16/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.28 | $28.03 |
| 7/23/2021 | $2,087.55 | $29.29 | $28.03 |
| 7/30/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.78 | $27.53 |
| 8/6/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.78 | $27.53 |
| 8/13/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.78 | $27.53 |
| 8/20/2021 | $2,092.15 | $28.78 | $27.59 |
| 8/27/2021 | $2,087.55 | $31.88 | $27.53 |
| 9/3/2021 | $2,149.51 | $28.78 | $28.42 |
| 9/10/2021 | $2,147.54 | $28.78 | $28.40 |
| 9/17/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.78 | $27.53 |
| 9/24/2021 | $2,087.55 | $28.78 | $27.53 |

Comment: Why are your calculated numbers different when the income is the same?  i.e  30.27, 28.21, 27.02, and 28.03 are not all the same percentage of 2087.55.  Something is changing week to week in both the employer's calculation and in yours..

Comment: There is an Additional Medicare Tax of 0.9% that is withheld after the first $200k of income from the same job. However, that should look like a single jump over one or two paychecks, but otherwise a flat percentage, and that's not what you are seeing here.

Comment: It would help to see all the numbers from a paystub or W2. According to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22885/what-accounts-for-the-average-fica-payroll-tax-paid-not-being-close-to-its-15 the Medicare tax is not on your entire gross, but after pre-tax medical insurance deductions and HSAs. What is the result of dividing "Medicare tax withheld" (box 6) by "Medicare wages and tips" (box 5) on your W-2?

Comment: Given the variability I think there's something being taken out pre-tax on a time period other than how the checks are--likely something that's flat per month.